# What function that satisfy: $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|\lambda_{n}|}{f(n)}\rightarrow 1$.

Tags: number-theory

$\lambda_{n}=\lbrace\frac{p}{q}|(\forall (p,q)\leq n)\rbrace$ for $(p,q)\in\mathbb{N}$.
For example: $ \ |\lambda_1|=\lbrace 1,0\rbrace \ ,|\lambda_2| =\lbrace 0, 1, \frac{1}{2}, 2\rbrace=\lbrace\lambda_1\cup\frac{1}{2},2\rbrace \ , |\lambda_3|=\lbrace \lambda_2\cup\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},3,\frac{3}{2}\rbrace \cdots$ 
 .

---

The sizes of these sets creates a sequence ${\lbrace2,4,8,12,20,24,36,44,56,64,84, \cdots\rbrace}$

---

then what function is asymptotic to the number of elements in the $\lambda_n$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

---

Thanks to @reuns i have come up with the following python code:

```
num = 100 
null = []
for i in range (num):
    for j in range(num)[1:]:
        if i/j not in null:
            null.append(i/j)
print(len(null) * 3.14159265359 ** 2 / (6 * num ** 2))
```

The code executed at num = 1000 gives: 0.9994356200720445. Which is very close to 1 :)

---

Comment: $\lambda_n=\{p/q:(\forall(p,q)\in{\bf N})\le n\}$ is a mathematical word salad – it's utterly incomprehensible. Maybe better to write out in words what you are trying to say.

Comment: Please don't confuse the set $\lambda_n$ with its cardinality $\#\lambda_n$

Comment: The sequence $2,4,8,12,20,23,32,40,52,60$ does not appear in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, so I suspect you have miscalculated. I wonder whether you mean http://oeis.org/A206350

Comment: Also, are you counting only reduced fractions? or are you counting, say, both $1/2$ and $2/4$?

Comment: Also, $\lambda_0=\{\phi\}$ doesn't make $\lambda_0$ the empty set, it makes it the set whose only element is the empty set.

Comment: Please engage with the comments and the answer, Noire.

Comment: I'm happy to see that you have corrected the terms in your sequence, and deleted the faulty reference to $\lambda_0$, and accepted an answer.

Comment: Thank you for correcting, Myerson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the OP meant the rationals $a/b$ with $a\le n,b\le n$, if so there are $$2\sum_{m\le n}\phi(m)+n+1 \sim \frac{6}{\pi^2}n^2$$ of them
(count the pairs $(a,b), b\le a\le n, \gcd(a,b)=1$, send them to the rationals $a/b$ and $b/a$, those that we missed are the integers)

Proof: $$\sum_{m\le n}\phi(m)=\sum_{m\le n}\sum_{d|m} \mu(d)\frac{m}{d}=\sum_{d\le n} \mu(d)\sum_{k\le n/d} k$$ $$=\sum_{d\le n} \mu(d)\frac{\lfloor  n/d\rfloor (\lfloor  n/d\rfloor+1)}{2} \sim \frac{ n^2}2 \sum_{d\le n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^2}\sim\frac{n^2}{2\zeta(2)}$$